# php mysql insert into error

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'character (name, address, birthplace, age,
>   birthdate) VALUES ( 'Alex','Villa V' at line 1

here

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO character (name, address, birthplace, age, birthdate) 
VALUES ( '$name','$address','$birthplace', '$age','$birthplace')";

if ($conn -> query($sql) === true){
    echo "New record created successfully ";

} else{
    echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".$conn -> error;
}

$conn -> close();
```

Everything else seems to be working fine i checked the syntax however the 
error wont disappear.

Comment: Lots of shouting in this question

Comment: Uppercase is considered as shouting...the first view on your question and i wouldn´t read it till the end...also format your code properly

Comment: Have you tried running this in your sql tools? e.g. phpmyadmin. What is your table structure?

Comment: this is the version of mysql database im using Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Software: MySQL
Software version: 5.5.27 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: character may be a reserved keyword. [lol late]

Comment: sorry for the uppercase this is my table structure

Comment: Like @Jonast92 says, look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html, character is a reserved word.  Don't have that for a table name.

Answer (score 3):

`character` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `character` (name, address, birthplace, age, birthdate) 
VALUES ( 'Alex','Villa Verde Subd.','July 5 1993', '17','July 5 1993')
```

BTW you should store the date values in a `date` column and not as a string. And storing the `age` is also not a good idea since it needs to be adjusted. It can be calculated from the birthdate.

Answer (score 1):

character is a reserved word in MySQL. you have to escape it with backticks:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `character` (name, address, birthplace, age, birthdate) VALUES ( '$name','$address','$birthplace', '$age','$birthplace')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `character` as table name as its reserve keyword. Use backticks

Answer (score 0):

`character` is a MySQL reserved word.

In order to do this use backticks, for example:

```
INSERT INTO `character`
```

Please see here for further information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html